# How can i mock a single function from my code with cypress to return it true

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

```
export const setReceptionMode = () => {
    if (window.location.host === process.env.VUE_APP_RECEPTION_HOST) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

This code is saved on a file.js
I want to run my cypress server and mock that function to it returns always true.
I tried stub and could not find a way

Comment: When is `setReceptionMode` called? Can you provide an example of the `cy.stub()` that you tried and how it did not work as you'd like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i'm running on before("", ()=>{)

Comment: i've tried cy.stub(receptionUtils,"setReceptionMode", true)